# Flatten RecursiveIteratorIterator array by children

Tags: php

I can't seem to figure out the best way to do this.  I have a `RecursiveIteratorIterator`.

```
$info = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new GroupIterator($X), # This is a class that implements RecursiveIterator
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);
```

<sub>Note: `GroupIterator` is a class that handles our custom formatted data</sub>

When I loop through it, I get exactly what I expect.

```
foreach($info as $data){
    echo $info->getDepth().'-'.$data."\n";
}
```

The output is:

```
0-a
1-b
2-c
2-d
1-e
2-f
0-g
1-h
2-i
```

This is correct, so far.  Now, what I want is to flatten the parents and children into a single array.  I want one row for each max-depth child.  The output I am trying to get is:

```
0-a 1-b 2-c
0-a 1-b 2-d
0-a 1-e 2-f
0-g 1-h 2-i
```

I can't figure out how to do this.  Each iteration over the loop gives me another row, how can I combine the rows together that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out.  [@ComFreek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19277471/206403) pointed me in the right direction.  Instead of using a counter, I used the current depth to check when I hit the lowest child, then I added the data to the final array, otherwise I added it to a temp array.

```
$finalArray = array();
$maxDepth = 2;
foreach($info as $data){
    $currentDepth = $info->getDepth();

    // Reset values for next parent
    if($currentDepth === 0){
        $currentRow = array();
    }

    // Add values for this depth
    $currentRow[$currentDepth] = $data;

    // When at lowest child, add to final array
    if($currentDepth === $maxDepth){
        $finalArray[] = $currentRow;
    }
}
```

Comment: @ComFreek: Yeah, me too. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a counter variable:

```
// rowNr loops through 0, 1, 2
$rowNr = 0;
$curData = [];
$outputData = [];

foreach($info as $data){
  // got last element, add the temp data to the actual array
  // and reset temp array and counter
  if ($rowNr == 2) {
    $outputData[] = $curData;
    $curData = [];
    $rowNr == 0;
  }
  else {
    // save temp data
    $curData[] = $info->getDepth() . '-' . $data;
  }
  $rowNr++;
}
```

Comment: This is close, but doesn't work quite how I envisioned.  The 4th iteration of the `foreach` is also at depth 2, so I wanted `0-a 1-b 2-d`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat I totally misunderstood your question, sorry. For building that table you want, is there any pattern or algorithm? Is it right that you always take the last n-depth element for the current row?

Comment: You did help point me in the right direction, though, so thanks.  Yeah.  Basically, I want the full "path" for all the lowest children (Does that make sense?).